# How to append a string to a column of a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

If I have a list of email addresses.

```
Name, Status,
JSmith, active,
ASmith, active,
JDoe, inactive
```

I want to pull those values from a list.csv file (the Name column) and append @mail.com to the end of each one.

Output file would look like this

```
JSmith@mail.com,
ASmith@mail.com,
JDoe@mail.com
```

```
Import-Csv list.csv | Format-Table column2
```

Comment: Is what you posted the exact output format you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that would be the exact output! That was so many years ago. Thank you for asking that question and I apologize for not getting back to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to create an array of email addresses as `[string]` instances, (which you can send to a file, if needed):

```
> (Import-csv list.csv).Name | % { "$_@mail.com" }
JSmith@mail.com
ASmith@mail.com
JDoe@mail.com
```

If you want to *modify* the `Name` column in the input to replace the names with email addresses (which you can re-export with `Export-Csv`, if needed):

```
> Import-csv list.csv | % { $_.Name += '@mail'; $_ }

Name        Status  
----        ------  
JSmith@mail active  
ASmith@mail active  
JDoe@mail   inactive
```

If you want to *add* a column for the email address:

```
> Import-csv list.csv | % { $name = $_.Name; $_ | Add-Member 'Email' "$name@mail.com"; $_ }

Name   Status   Email          
----   ------   -----          
JSmith active   JSmith@mail.com
ASmith active   ASmith@mail.com
JDoe   inactive JDoe@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try.

**input.csv:**

```
Name,Status
JSmith,active
ASmith,active
JDoe,inactive
```

**code (files are on my desktop):**

```
# import csv file
Import-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\input.csv" -Delimiter "," |
    # create calculated property
    Select-Object @{ Name = "Email"; Expression = { "$($_.Name)@mail.com" } } |
    # remove column header for export
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Email |
    # export to simple text file
    Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.txt"
```

**output.txt:**

```
JSmith@mail.com
ASmith@mail.com
JDoe@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
Import-Csv Test.csv | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property ([Ordered] @{
    "Name" = $_.Name
    "Status" = $_.Status
    "Email" = "{0}@mail.com" -f $_.Name
  })
} | Export-Csv Test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This outputs a new CSV file with a new column. (This example requires PowerShell v3 due to the `[Ordered]` attribute. You will need to remove `[Ordered]` for the example to work in PowerShell v2.)

If you just want to import the CSV file and output the Name column only with `@mail.com` appended:

```
Import-Csv Test.csv | ForEach-Object {
  "{0}@mail.com" -f $_.Name
} | Out-File Output.txt
```

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm curious as to why your indents are only 2 spaces wide, are you using an alternate editor like PowerGUI?

Answer (score 0):

just do it

```
$yourfile="c:\temp\youfile.csv"

(Import-Csv $yourfile  | select *, @{N="Email"; E={"{0}@mail.com" -f $_.Name }}) | 
export-csv $yourfile -notype
```